# page layout on prawn unable to set inside class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, prawn

i have searched in prawn about page layout in prawn and it showed this

```
pdf = Prawn::Document.new(:page_size => "A4", :page_layout => :landscape)
```

pdf.text doesnt print anything

but when i try this i'm getting undefined method

```
page_layout :landscape
```

added after super()

this is my whole code

```
class ProductPdfGenerate < Prawn::Document
    require 'open-uri'
    def initialize(order_items)
        super()
        @document = Prawn::Document.new(:page_size => "A4", :page_layout => :landscape)
        @order_items = order_items
        @order_items.each_with_index do |oi, i|
            if oi.case.present? && Model.where(magento_model_id: oi.case.model_id).first.present?
                style_image = oi.case.image_preview.url(:custom_image)
                model = Model.where(magento_model_id: oi.case.model_id).first
                # image open(style_image), width: "200".to_f, height: "400".to_f
                image open(style_image), width: "#{model.aspect_ratio_width.to_f/2.54*72}".to_f, height: "#{model.aspect_ratio_height.to_f/2.54*72}".to_f
                text "\n \n \n"
                text "Model: #{model.name}"
                text "Model Category: #{model.category_type}"
                text "Style: #{oi.case.style.try(:name)} "
                text "Order Id: #{oi.order_id}"
            else
                image open("https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/take-my-order/default/missing.png")
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this syntax, which works for my code:

```
def initialize(order_items)
    super :page_size => "A4", :page_layout => :landscape
    @order_items = order_items
...
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a fairly old question, however I found it during my journey through the Prawn basics and thus want to give an answer nevertheless (that hopefully helps future visitors).

According to [the Prawn Manual](http://prawnpdf.org/manual.pdf) (Page 4), there are three ways to instanciate a new PDF. Here, the OP has chosen the first way
`@document = Prawn::Document.new...`.
To change the page (e.g. add text to it), you would now have to call

```
@document.text "Model: #{model.name}"
```

instead of just `text "Model: #{model.name}"`.

However, there is a way to omit the repeated call of @document, being a block call like so:

```
Prawn::Document.generate(<generator options like layout etc here>) do
  text "Model: #{model.name}"
end
```

This way, the method "text" can be successfully mapped to the object created by calling the block method "generate" and needs no further specification (e.g. @document.text).

Happy coding.